# Kettle's spoon.bat can't open

Tags: kettle

I tried a lot of things but I couldn't figure it out,want to seek the help.Thank you very much.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDil0.png)

My JDK is 1.8 and I have no problems with the environment configuration. There is no space on the path, and most of the ways have been tried, it seems that it can not be solved

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The error message is "InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static final". This means KettleUrlClassLoader is trying to do something your JVM doesn't like. You'll either have to fix the code or find an older less restrictive VM I'd guess, or get an updated version of the code that works with newer VMs.

Comment: It's also suspicious it's trying to load the Sun classes: I thought many of them had gone away. What JVM are you using, an Oracle one or someone else's OpenJDK-based one?

Comment: I'd guess that it was written for a JVM before 1.8 anyway because it's specifying MaxPermSize (see the warning in your screenshot) although that's not conclusive.